# extract a value from a text field using selenium RC and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using Selenium + Java bindings and I want to know if anyone has an idea how to extract a value from a text field. I tried the following code, but without success:

```
String value = selenium.getValue(lss.get(i))
logger.info("ma val :" + selenium.getValue(remplace));
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Are you absolutely sure you are giving the right locators to the function? Make sure by using [`highlight()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#highlight%28java.lang.String%29) on it, too.

Comment: yes , you are right  the locator wasn't the right one , thank you

Comment: :), please post an answer (and accept it) or even delete the question then, we like our Stack Overflow nice and clean.

Comment: this is the answer :   val=selenium.getValue("//span[text()=\""+remplace+" \"]/following-sibling::input");
        logger.info("ma val :"+selenium.getValue("//span[text()=\""+remplace+" \"]/following-sibling::input"));

Comment: yes i know but i don't have the right to answer my own question because i'm with less than 10 reputations so i need to wait for 8 hours after asking ...

Answer (score 0):

The OP given answer is as follows:

```
val=selenium.getValue("//span[text()=\""+remplace+" \"]/following-sibling::input");
logger.info("ma val :"+selenium.getValue("//span[text()=\""+remplace+" \"]/following-sibling::input"));
```